# Find range of dates based on a column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, group-by, gaps-and-islands

I'm looking to group the data below by `ITEM` and "change in" `STATUS`, but for the below example would expect 3 lines due to the status switching back again.

Presently I'm using `MIN(FROM_DT) AND MAX(TO_DATE)` but only get 2 lines, due to there only being 2 different values in the `STATUS` column.

Expected result:

```
ITEM    FROM_DT     TO_DT       STATUS
ITEM1   02/01/2020  15/05/2020  0
ITEM1   15/05/2020  18/05/2020  1
ITEM1   18/05/2020  31/12/9999  0
```

Sample Data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AH_TEMP](
    [ITEM] [varchar](24) NULL,
    [FROM_DT] [datetime] NULL,
    [TO_DT] [datetime] NULL,
    [EXCL] [bit] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO AH_TEMP 
VALUES  
    ('ITEM1','2020-01-02 22:57:01.200','2020-01-07 22:54:52.930','0'),
    ('ITEM1','2020-01-07 22:57:21.950','2020-02-03 22:54:30.500','0'),
    ('ITEM1','2020-02-03 22:58:21.180','2020-03-02 22:54:27.253','0'),
    ('ITEM1','2020-03-02 22:56:30.737','2020-03-18 17:21:23.390','0'),
    ('ITEM1','2020-03-18 17:21:23.403','2020-03-19 09:05:38.060','0'),
    ('ITEM1','2020-03-19 09:05:38.063','2020-03-19 13:57:03.567','0'),
    ('ITEM1','2020-03-19 13:57:03.570','2020-03-19 23:01:41.403','0'),
    ('ITEM1','2020-03-19 23:03:49.900','2020-03-20 23:02:25.437','0'),
    ('ITEM1','2020-03-20 23:04:53.610','2020-04-01 22:59:39.220','0'),
    ('ITEM1','2020-04-01 23:01:45.620','2020-05-01 22:59:09.153','0'),
    ('ITEM1','2020-05-01 23:01:11.980','2020-05-14 14:30:21.930','0'),
    ('ITEM1','2020-05-14 14:30:21.930','2020-05-14 22:57:24.753','0'),
    ('ITEM1','2020-05-14 22:59:17.623','2020-05-15 17:48:34.000','0'),
    ('ITEM1','2020-05-15 17:48:35.000','2020-05-15 22:57:15.923','0'),
    ('ITEM1','2020-05-15 22:59:11.933','2020-05-16 22:54:31.750','1'),
    ('ITEM1','2020-05-16 22:56:26.793','2020-05-18 22:55:01.050','1'),
    ('ITEM1','2020-05-18 23:00:23.103','2020-05-21 22:55:24.400','0'),
    ('ITEM1','2020-05-21 22:57:01.723','2020-06-01 23:00:21.823','0'),
    ('ITEM1','2020-06-01 23:03:12.467','2020-06-08 22:55:20.393','0'),
    ('ITEM1','2020-06-08 22:58:27.710','9999-12-31 00:00:00.000','0');
```

Returns:

```
+-------+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| ITEM  |         FROM_DT         |          TO_DT          | STATUS |
+-------+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| ITEM1 | 2020-01-02 22:57:01.200 | 2020-01-07 22:54:52.930 |      0 |
| ITEM1 | 2020-01-07 22:57:21.950 | 2020-02-03 22:54:30.500 |      0 |
| ITEM1 | 2020-02-03 22:58:21.180 | 2020-03-02 22:54:27.253 |      0 |
| ITEM1 | 2020-03-02 22:56:30.737 | 2020-03-18 17:21:23.390 |      0 |
| ITEM1 | 2020-03-18 17:21:23.403 | 2020-03-19 09:05:38.060 |      0 |
| ITEM1 | 2020-03-19 09:05:38.063 | 2020-03-19 13:57:03.567 |      0 |
| ITEM1 | 2020-03-19 13:57:03.570 | 2020-03-19 23:01:41.403 |      0 |
| ITEM1 | 2020-03-19 23:03:49.900 | 2020-03-20 23:02:25.437 |      0 |
| ITEM1 | 2020-03-20 23:04:53.610 | 2020-04-01 22:59:39.220 |      0 |
| ITEM1 | 2020-04-01 23:01:45.620 | 2020-05-01 22:59:09.153 |      0 |
| ITEM1 | 2020-05-01 23:01:11.980 | 2020-05-14 14:30:21.930 |      0 |
| ITEM1 | 2020-05-14 14:30:21.930 | 2020-05-14 22:57:24.753 |      0 |
| ITEM1 | 2020-05-14 22:59:17.623 | 2020-05-15 17:48:34.000 |      0 |
| ITEM1 | 2020-05-15 17:48:35.000 | 2020-05-15 22:57:15.923 |      0 |
| ITEM1 | 2020-05-15 22:59:11.933 | 2020-05-16 22:54:31.750 |      1 |
| ITEM1 | 2020-05-16 22:56:26.793 | 2020-05-18 22:55:01.050 |      1 |
| ITEM1 | 2020-05-18 23:00:23.103 | 2020-05-21 22:55:24.400 |      0 |
| ITEM1 | 2020-05-21 22:57:01.723 | 2020-06-01 23:00:21.823 |      0 |
| ITEM1 | 2020-06-01 23:03:12.467 | 2020-06-08 22:55:20.393 |      0 |
| ITEM1 | 2020-06-08 22:58:27.710 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00.000 |      0 |
+-------+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
```

Comment: Expected Result, 3 rows, based on the STAUS,ITEM

ITEM FROM_DT TO_DT STATUS
ITEM1 02/01/2020 15/05/2020 0
ITEM1 15/05/2020 18/05/2020 1
ITEM1 18/05/2020 31/12/9999 0

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62290951/edit) your question with updates rather than adding comments. And also, please delete that picture of data and paste the data back in plain text so others can copy it to test against.

Comment: This is the tool I use to generate table data: https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Comment: Good day @AndyH, Do you need image of the expected result or you need a query that return the expected result?!? Query cannot work on "sample" image. If you need query then you should provide queries to create the sample table and to insert the sample data. This we will be able to write and test a solution. In the meantime, think about this point: a SET of returned data does not have any order unless you configure the order using "order by". In order to get your expected result (3 groups) we need to know what is the order of the data. Should we sort the data by from_Dt column?

Comment: @EricBrandt thankyou,  ive added the ascii table.

Comment: @RonenAriely  thankyou for your reply.  data us sorted by FROM_DT column and the column to identify the change on is STATUS/EXCL

Comment: sorry for the poorly written first question..  will try and include  all info in the future!

Comment: Awesome work @AndyH, thanks for providing the missing information. I added another solution to one you already got.

Comment: Thankyou so much @EricBrandt

Comment: Thankyou @RonenAriely

Comment: both solutions worked equally well..  i had started with the LAG option, but failed to use the sum, so ended up with 4-5 changes which then wouldnt had worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for posting the missing information (DDL+DML),

Please check if the following solve your needs

```
;With MyCTE as (
    SELECT 
        ITEM, FROM_DT, TO_DT, EXCL
        , MyGROUP = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FROM_DT) - RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY EXCL ORDER BY FROM_DT)  
    FROM AH_TEMP
)
SELECT ITEM, MIN(FROM_DT), MAX(TO_DT), EXCL as [STATUS]
FROM MyCTE
GROUP BY ITEM, EXCL, MyGROUP
ORDER BY MIN(FROM_DT)
GO
```

Comment: @DaleK Why did you removed you comment? Now my thanks comment seems not relevant to anything. It was response to you saying that you like it, and now it it has no relation to any previous message

Comment: "`Because you'd seen the comment which was my intent and its not helpful for other people in the long run. Unless a comment provides additional value to the question it will get deleted at some point in time. Its all part of leaving clean, neat questions and answers. – Dale K`" This is awful approach in my personal opinion. Make me think ten time why should I spend time to respond

Comment: @RonenAriely i edited slightly to add the ability to also split on the ITEM

 MyGROUP = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM ORDER BY FROM_DT) - RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM, EXCL ORDER BY FROM_DT)

Comment: Make sense @AndyH :-)

Answer (score 2):

By using `lag` to detect the change in status, and then `sum`ing the change in status we can group by this sum to give the grouping required.

```
declare @Test table (ITEM varchar(24), FROM_DT date, TO_DT date, [STATUS] bit)

INSERT INTO @test VALUES  ('ITEM1','2020-01-02 22:57:01.200','2020-01-07 22:54:52.930','0');
INSERT INTO @test VALUES  ('ITEM1','2020-01-07 22:57:21.950','2020-02-03 22:54:30.500','0');
INSERT INTO @test VALUES  ('ITEM1','2020-02-03 22:58:21.180','2020-03-02 22:54:27.253','0');
INSERT INTO @test VALUES  ('ITEM1','2020-03-02 22:56:30.737','2020-03-18 17:21:23.390','0');
INSERT INTO @test VALUES  ('ITEM1','2020-03-18 17:21:23.403','2020-03-19 09:05:38.060','0');
INSERT INTO @test VALUES  ('ITEM1','2020-03-19 09:05:38.063','2020-03-19 13:57:03.567','0');
INSERT INTO @test VALUES  ('ITEM1','2020-03-19 13:57:03.570','2020-03-19 23:01:41.403','0');
INSERT INTO @test VALUES  ('ITEM1','2020-03-19 23:03:49.900','2020-03-20 23:02:25.437','0');
INSERT INTO @test VALUES  ('ITEM1','2020-03-20 23:04:53.610','2020-04-01 22:59:39.220','0');
INSERT INTO @test VALUES  ('ITEM1','2020-04-01 23:01:45.620','2020-05-01 22:59:09.153','0');
INSERT INTO @test VALUES  ('ITEM1','2020-05-01 23:01:11.980','2020-05-14 14:30:21.930','0');
INSERT INTO @test VALUES  ('ITEM1','2020-05-14 14:30:21.930','2020-05-14 22:57:24.753','0');
INSERT INTO @test VALUES  ('ITEM1','2020-05-14 22:59:17.623','2020-05-15 17:48:34.000','0');
INSERT INTO @test VALUES  ('ITEM1','2020-05-15 17:48:35.000','2020-05-15 22:57:15.923','0');
INSERT INTO @test VALUES  ('ITEM1','2020-05-15 22:59:11.933','2020-05-16 22:54:31.750','1');
INSERT INTO @test VALUES  ('ITEM1','2020-05-16 22:56:26.793','2020-05-18 22:55:01.050','1');
INSERT INTO @test VALUES  ('ITEM1','2020-05-18 23:00:23.103','2020-05-21 22:55:24.400','0');
INSERT INTO @test VALUES  ('ITEM1','2020-05-21 22:57:01.723','2020-06-01 23:00:21.823','0');
INSERT INTO @test VALUES  ('ITEM1','2020-06-01 23:03:12.467','2020-06-08 22:55:20.393','0');
INSERT INTO @test VALUES  ('ITEM1','2020-06-08 22:58:27.710','9999-12-31 00:00:00.000','0');

select ITEM, min(FROM_DT), max(TO_DT), [STATUS]
from (
  select *
    , sum(case when coalesce(lag,0) <> [STATUS] then 1 else 0 end) over (order by FROM_DT, TO_DT) GroupBy
  from (
    select *
      , lag([STATUS]) over (order by FROM_DT) lag
    from @Test
  ) X
) Y
group by ITEM, GroupBy, [STATUS]
order by ITEM, GroupBy;
```

Gives:

```
ITEM    FROM_DT                 TO_DT                   STATUS
ITEM1   2020-01-02 22:57:01.200 2020-05-15 22:57:15.923 0
ITEM1   2020-05-15 22:59:11.933 2020-05-18 22:55:01.050 1
ITEM1   2020-05-18 23:00:23.103 9999-12-31 00:00:00.000 0
```

If you are interested in seeing how it works then just run:

```
select *
  , sum(case when coalesce(lag,0) <> [STATUS] then 1 else 0 end) over (order by FROM_DT, TO_DT) GroupBy
from (
  select *
    , lag([STATUS]) over (order by FROM_DT) lag
  from @Test
) X
order by ITEM, FROM_DT, TO_DT
```